# Stack of Paper vs. Stack of Papers

Tags: word-choice, nouns, word-usage, grammatical-number

I question the usage of "stack of paper" vs. "stack of papers". I purchase a ream of paper, and set it on a desk. In that process, does it change from a ream of paper to a stack of papers - changing from a singular word to a plural?

In both cases it is still 500 sheets of paper.

When is it proper to use stack of paper vs. stack of papers?

A stack of bricks is always plural isn't it?

Comment: A stack of papers is something a professor grades; a stack of paper is something a printer uses.

Comment: Please look up *paper* in a dictionary of your choice, paying attention to which meaning is marked as countable and which as uncountable.

Answer (score 3):

When the ream has just been removed from the packaging, it is a stack of [*paper*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/papers) (definition 1):

> A material made of cellulose pulp, derived mainly from wood, rags, and certain grasses, processed into flexible sheets or rolls by deposit from an aqueous suspension, and used chiefly for writing, printing, drawing, wrapping, and covering walls.

Once it has been printed upon, it is a stack of *papers* (definition 3)

> One or more sheets of paper bearing writing or printing, especially:
>   a. A formal written composition intended to be published, presented, or read aloud; a scholarly essay or treatise.
>   b. A piece of written work for school; a report or theme.
>   c. An official document, especially one establishing the identity of the bearer. Often used in the plural.